# android restricting apk install for small screens

Tags: android, android-manifest, apk

How can I restrict my apk to not install on small devices, I know about the support-screens parameter but as I understand correctly , it won't work if user is installing directly from apk.

Comment: What do you mean by 'installing directly from apk'? That's the standard way of installing an app on Adnroid i.e. from an apk file.

Comment: this may be useful to you,decalring screenSupport in Manifest http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html I have no complete understaning about this..but right now I am also reading this page so posted

Comment: I know you got the answer but Still what about this,I never used..but Try android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" in this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can only restrict devices that can see your app in the market. If they have your apk, there's no stopping them. You can however check the resolution on startup, and display an alert or something.

Comment: "You can however check the resolution on startup, and display an alert or something" and also stop your app to go further from Splash Screen

Comment: @Frankenstein that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: @VaibhavMishra did you checked out my comment on your question,does it help anyway?

Comment: @Franjenstein of course , however that's only for the market , so I cannot really test it, that thing is for market filtering, I included it in manifest.