# Only available for Tablet device

Tags: android, tablet, android-5.0-lollipop

An Android app has been developed only for Tablet devices. I defined the supports-screens only for these size. I know that play-store is going to allow just Tablet devices.

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
android:normalScreens="false"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true"
android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

But if I try to install the apk directly on a smartphone works, but it must not work. The smartphone allow the installation.

Is it that normal? I´m trying to use Android-L and I don´t know if has to be consider.

Thank you for any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app will still install on your device if you push over ADB like you are doing. Those settings prevent the app from showing up on or being installed on handsets in the play store.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html

There is more detail there. Also try uploading your app in the developer center (where you would publish your app) and you'll see what I'm talking about there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent direct install from apk. Android version doesn't matter.

You should check for screen resolution on startup, then if the device doesn't fit your requirements, inform the user about allowed devices and close the app.

See similar question here [android restricting apk install for small screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092101/android-restricting-apk-install-for-small-screens)